# German characters in lco file scrlttr2

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2

I'd like to use an lco file for my personal information. Unfortunately there are several german characters `(ß, ä, ...)` contained in that file, which aren't displayed correctly in the final pdf.
Using `\RequirePackage` or `\usepackage` didn't solve my problem. Either did `\RequirePackage[latin1]{inputenc}`.
Does someone has any advice?

Regards
Andi

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. Most modern editors use utf8.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Bernard.
Unfortunately I still didn't manage to accomplish what I wanted to do. 
I'm pretty sure I tried every combiniation where to put those commands (in the .lco and .tex, also with \ReqirePackage) but if the text from one file works the other doesn't. :(

Comment: Another possibility would be to first convert you file to utf8. An editor like TeXmaker can do that and usually can detect correctly the real encoding of the file.

Comment: This is the solution!
The problem was that the two files were encoded differently. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no problem if *every* file is UTF-8 encoded.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{andileni.lco}
\ProvidesFile{andileni.lco}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Andi Leni}
\setkomavar{signature}{Andi Leni}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Müllerstraße\\Würzburg}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[
  foldmarks=true,
  foldmarks=blmtP,
  andileni,
  version=last
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Üöäß\\Berlin}
\opening{Dear Üöäß,}

you have a very strange name.

\closing{Best wishes}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

The `filecontents*` environment is only used for making the example selfcontained.

[image]